# A (swift) project is crashing when cancel facebook authentication

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My project use Firebase and Facebook Authentication. It works fine, but when I choose to cancel the Facebook Authentication (the first time when i fetch the uid) the project crash.
Here is the method i use:

```
   func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
        let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
        Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (user, error) in
            // [START_EXCLUDE]

            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            self.uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

            self.firstFetch()


            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
        print("logged in")
    }
```

Can Anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the whole implementation of this function was wrong, because it was fetching the user no matter if it was authenticated or not. Here is the new method I wrote:

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: 

    FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
            if error != nil {
                print("look a at your.. errm.. code, please", error.localizedDescription)
            } else if result.isCancelled {
                print("houston, we have a situation: the player cancelled the auth request")
            } else {
            let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
            Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (user, error) in
                self.uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
                print("you're in, remember: with great power comes great responsibility!")
                self.firstFetch()
                }
            }
        }
```